# Subscribe Объявление было отмечено как устаревшее

Tags: angular, angular2

Ребята установил 13 версию, перетаскиваю метод из старого проекта и `subscribe` зачеркнуто.

Понимаю, что устаревшее, но как изменить не понимаю. Подскажите куда копать.

```
registration = (Email: string, Username: string, Password: string) => {
    this.api.regUser(Email, Username, Password).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
        },
        error => {       
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.subscribe({
    next: data => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    },
    error: e => {
        // ...         
    }
});
```

Comment: cпасибо, вы мне очень помогли.